# Proven and stable BPEL / BPMN technologies?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management, bpel, weblogic-integration

After various difficulties with a proprietary BPM tool (SAP) I want to take a birds eye view on the current market and the tools which are currently available.

Can anyone share experience with those tools, either from other vendors (IBM, Oracle) or open source? I'm particularly interested in mapping functionality and UI-integration features.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jBPM5 it's a great alternative. Right now jBPM5 supports the latest BPMN2 specifiction from business process modeling and execution. jBPM5 also provides the possibility to integrate the web-based process designer and tooling inside your applications. Take a look at www.jbpm.org and my personal blog for more information and material: http://salaboy.wordpress.com

Answer (score 2):

We had evaluated various open source BPM engine like JBPM, Activiti ,Active VOS,Bonitasoft BPM 
We finally chose JBPM5
Reason being:
1) Great Web Designer for process designing
2) Integration with Rules and Events
3) BPMN2.0 notation AND bpmn2 executable